# Is this plant lantana camara? If not what is it?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I was in a botanical garden recently and wasn't able to find the tag on this plant. The diameter of the entire flower tended to be around 5cm.

Google seems to suggest its lantana camara but I'm not 100% convinced yet.

[image]

When rubbed, its leaves produced a minty aroma

Comment: It does seem very similar. Why do you doubt?

Comment: It is *Lantana camara* you are correct.  There are many hybrids out there as well.

Answer (score -1):

It is Lantana camara, you can check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lantana_camara

Comment: Someone (not me), downvoted your answer. If this can be helpful for you, the reason might be that you do not give enough details in the answer itself. You should probably give more information such as key criteria that allow the confirmation of the identification of this plant.